# np.outer output changes when stored in an array

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have a NxN matrix which I am interested in its eigenvalue decomposition in order to obtain P=exp(tA). In order to evaluate the P_ij(t) functions, I want to prepare a E=NxNxN matrix where E is the outer product of v[i] and `np.linalg.inv(v)[i]` and `v[i]` is one of the eigenvectors.

The sample code with my 3x3 toy matrix is as

```py
def eig_trial(A,n):
        v,w=np.linalg.eig(A)
        w_inv=np.linalg.inv(
        eigs=np.array([[[0 for k in xrange(len(v))] for j in xrange(n)] for i in xrange(n)])
        for i in range(len(v)):
            q=np.outer(np.array(w[:,i]),np.array(w_inv[i]))
            eigs[i]=q            
        pprint.pprint(eigs)


A=np.asarray([[6,3,-2],[-4, -1, 2],[13,9,-3]])
eig_trial(A,3)
```

The problem is, `q=np.outer(...)`, which is the correct value, is not equal to `eigs[i]`.

Is there a reason why I can't store this into a matrix? If it helps, I am using Canopy Version: 2.1.9.3717 (64 bit) and Python 2.7.13.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the dtype of `eigs`?

Comment: @hpaulj print eigs.dtype gives int32

Comment: That `eigs` array, as you create it can only store integer values, not floats.  `eig=np.zeros((len(v),n,n))` should work better. look at its dtype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `eigs` array that you initialize has dtype `int`

```
In [96]: alist = ([[0 for k in range(5)] for j in range(3)])                                   
In [97]: arr = np.array(alist)                                                                 
In [98]: alist                                                                                 
Out[98]: [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
In [99]: arr                                                                                   
Out[99]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

And do some assignments:

```
In [100]: arr[0] = np.arange(5)                                                                
In [101]: alist[0] = np.arange(5)                                                              
In [102]: arr[1] = np.arange(5)*.1                                                             
In [103]: alist[1] = np.arange(5)*.1
```

`arr` is still integers, even though the last assignment includes floats

```
In [104]: arr                                                                                  
Out[104]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
In [105]: alist                                                                                
Out[105]: [array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), array([0. , 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]), [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

You can see the truncation more clearly with:

```
In [108]: arr[1] = np.arange(5)*1.3                                                            
In [109]: arr                                                                                  
Out[109]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 5],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

If the array started as float dtype:

```
    In [110]: arr = np.zeros((3,5))  # float dtype default                                         
    In [111]: arr[0] = np.arange(5)                                                                
    In [112]: arr[1] = np.arange(5)*1.3                                                            
    In [113]: arr                                                                                  
    Out[113]: 
    array([[0. , 1. , 2. , 3. , 4. ],
           [0. , 1.3, 2.6, 3.9, 5.2],
           [0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ]])
```

You could have also initialed `eigs` with `0.` instead of `0`

```
In [114]: np.array([0. for _ in range(5)])                                                     
Out[114]: array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
```

but the `zeros` I used above is faster (and simpler)

You didn't need to assign the full nested depth of the list. Just the first layer would have been enough.  List's can assigned anything:

```
In [115]: alist = [None for _ in range(5)]                                                     
In [116]: alist                                                                                
Out[116]: [None, None, None, None, None]
In [117]: alist[0] = np.arange(5)                                                              
In [118]: alist[1] = 32                                                                        
In [119]: alist[2] = np.ones((3,2))                                                            
In [120]: alist                                                                                
Out[120]: 
[array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), 32, array([[1., 1.],
        [1., 1.],
        [1., 1.]]), None, None]
```

The array assignment `arr[0] = np.arange(5)` is different.  There's an implied `arr[0,:,:] = ...`.  If the selected slot in the `arr` does not match with the RHS array, you'll get an error.  `match` means either exact match in shape, or match in broadcasting terms.

When you run into problems like this, experiment with the small parts of the code as I demonstrate.  It's a lot easier to track down problems with small interactive examples.

Answer (score 0):

I literally have no idea but I found a weird workaround. The problem is due to eigs being an array. It works if it is a list of lists.

```py
def eig_trial(A,n):
        v,w=np.linalg.eig(A)
        w_inv=np.linalg.inv(
        eigs=[[[0 for k in xrange(len(v))] for j in xrange(n)] for i in xrange(n)] #np.array dropped
        for i in range(len(v)):
            q=np.outer(np.array(w[:,i]),np.array(w_inv[i]))
            eigs[i]=q
        eigs=np.asarray(eigs) #now convert it to an np array
        pprint.pprint(eigs)


A=np.asarray([[6,3,-2],[-4, -1, 2],[13,9,-3]])
eig_trial(A,3)
```

I would be very happy if someone explains why, but this is at least a solution.

Comment: A list can contain anyrhing,  Look a `eigs` before yoy use the `array` function.